# Prove or disprove the convergence of multiplication of two sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Say $a_n$ is a bounded sequence and $b_n$ converges to $L$, $L \ne 0$. We need to prove or disprove the statement that $a_n\cdot b_n$ is convergent.

I have a counterexample here. Since $a_n$ is a bounded sequence. Let $a_n = (-1)^n$. Let $b_n = 2$. Thus, we get $a_n \cdot b_n = 2(-1)^n$ which is not convergent.

Thus, the statement is false. Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is absolutely right as, for example, also for $a_n=\cos \left(\frac{\pi}2n\right)$ or others periodic sequences.

Indeed in your case

- for $n$ even $\implies a_n \cdot b_n = 2(-1)^n\to 2$
- for $n$ odd $\implies a_n \cdot b_n = 2(-1)^n\to -2$

therefore the limit doesn't exist.